# Next.js app for development running on docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, next.js

I'm trying to set up a docker container running a next.js app for development purposes using docker compose, so it can be used along side other containers (such an api or other services), and what I need is the next.js app could compile any change made in real time after an update in the source code is made. So I created a volume for the container mapped to the source code on my host machine. The thing is that the app on the container does not update after some changes are applied on the source code, the container actually updates the files (the volume is mapped correctly) but the application does not applies the changes and does not compile again. The output console for docker compose is this, saying that @next/swc-linux-x64 is not installed:

[image]

I believe that there is some issue with the image because when I run `npm run dev` on my local machine it does not shows that warning and it works well (after some change is made in the source code the app is updated and compiles the changes):

[image]

So the questions are: Is it possible to create a development container for a next.js app using Docker? And it'll be able to update/compile after some change is made from the source code on my host machine? What could be the issue that the app does not update any change being made from the source code?

My host OS is Windows 11. And node version: 18.14.0

My project structure is:

[image]

The files that I'm using are the following:

`Dockerfile.dev`:

```
FROM node:18.14.0

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY /public .
COPY /src .

EXPOSE 3000

ENV NODE_ENV=development

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

`docker-compose.dev.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  frontend:
    environment:
     NODE_ENV: development
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
    command: npm run dev
    networks:
      - my_network

networks:
  my_network:
```

`next.config.js`:

```js
/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */
module.exports = {
    output: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'standalone' : 'module',
};
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.2",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.1.6",
    "gray-matter": "^4.0.3",
    "next": "^13.1.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "remark": "^14.0.2",
    "remark-html": "^15.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: You might find it simpler to stand up the back end and dependencies using containers, but use a normal non-container Node environment for front-end development.  Since the actual application runs in the browser it can't use things like Docker networking, and you wind up having to work around Docker's core immutable-image and filesystem-isolation features.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for your answer. Yes, I'm thinking that I'll end up doing that. I was just looking for an option to facilitate the initialization for development environment for some coworkers (cause is for a collaborating project) but thanks, i'll reconsider that.

Answer (score 3):

### Try a different stack

For troubleshooting, you can try a different image and runtime, for example, `bun` instead of `node`. Here's how I use it with BunJS:

`Dockerfile`

```
# Use an official Bun runtime as the base image
FROM oven/bun:debian

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json (if available)
COPY package*.json ./

# Install project dependencies
RUN bun --bun install

# Copy the rest of the application code into the container
COPY . .

# The port that the Next.js app runs on
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the Next.js app
CMD ["bun", "run", "dev"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
services:
  nextjs:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    networks:
      - my_network
```

### Still see the issue?

If you still see the issue, then it is not the image you were using, nor with Node.

Most likely, it is your host OS settings (ex. max limit for file watchers) or your NextJS settings (ex. custom code settings breaking the hot reload).

### Try increasing the file watchers

You can also try increasing the limit of file watchers.

1. In your host machine, open the sysctl file:

```bash
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

2. Add this line

```ini
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1048576
```

3. Apply the changes:

```bash
sudo sysctl -p
```

You have to do this on the host machine because the host limits the container number of watchers.

#### Setting it on the container instead

However, if you want to do this on the container instead, you have to run it with admin privileges.

Just be aware that this can pose a security risk if your container has a malicious code.

1. Add this line to your `Dockerfile`

```
RUN echo "fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1048576" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

2. Run with privileges

```bash
docker run --privileged your-image-name
```

Or with `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  nextjs:
    # ... rest of your settings ...
    cap_add:
      - SYS_ADMIN
```